# Restore data from encrypted iOS backup without respective device

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, restore, encryption

My iPhone stopped working but I have encrypted backups on my machine. I won't get a new iPhone but I obviously want to extract all my data. Is there any tool how I can extract the data without buying a new iPhone?

I know about many 3rd party tools, but they all have a cost behind it, and I'm wondering if you know a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can decrypt an iTunes Encrypted Backup (when the password is known) using backup_tool.py from [iphone-dataprotection](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dataprotection/source/browse/python_scripts/backup_tool.py) on Google Code.

Navigate to an suitable destination in Terminal, then run the following:

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/iphone-dataprotection/
python iphone-dataprotection/python_scripts/backup_tool.py ~/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync/Backup/backupname decrypted
```

<sup>Replace `backupname` with the encrypted backup folder name.</sup>

The tool will prompt you for the encryption password, then output the decrypted backup to the folder ‘decrypted’.

Comment: I do have the password, but is there any more information about this tool? I would like to not run my data through a CLI tool I know nothing more of but the name.

Comment: @supersize You can read the python code of the tool before you run it, I have experience with the tool I've used it a few times but it's been a long time and I don't have a source of any more information, there might be more available on the Google Code but that's basically shut down now